# Game Center can't find existing turn-based matches

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, game-center

I'm writing a turn-based iPhone game and I can't seem to find my own games.
I have three accounts trying to matchmake in my game - one on my iPhone 5, and two different Game Center test accounts created in the iPhone simulator which I switch between all playing my game through the Game Center sandbox. Unfortunately, they never find eachother and always create new games on their own. How can I fix it so they will ALWAYS find an existing match, if there is one available, and only create a new game if there are NO open games?

Comment: How thoroughly did you test? It can take a short while until the existing match is chosen to serve your subsequent request. Also, how are you determining whether something is a pre-existing match? Some insight into your matchmaking code and handler may help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController to find matches and doing something similar to this:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;       
GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
mmvc.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In your delegate method you can do this to figure out if this was a brand new game or if you're joining an existing game:

```
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match {

    int numberOfParticipants = [match.participants count];
    // check the number of valid participant ids to find out if you need to know if this is a "new" game or not.
    ....
```

For match making to pair up a user with an existing game, the opponent player must have "completed" their turn by calling this method on GKTurnedBasedMatch:

```
- (void)endTurnWithNextParticipants:(NSArray *)nextParticipants turnTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout matchData:(NSData*)matchData completionHandler:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionHandler;
```